# When is there a natural copower for models of a geometric theory?

Tags: logic, category-theory, universal-algebra

First let's establish the notion of an [embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Universal_algebra_and_model_theory) as it is in universal algebra. Now consider the category of models of a [geometric theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+theory) over a (nonempty) signature. Now we can make sense of the title question.

Giving more information, when given a *finite* model of this theory, I want to always be able to construct an infinite (for my interests, countably infinite, but more general answers that imply countably infinite are welcome) model into which the original one embeds. If our category had (infinite) coproducts there would be a natural sense in which we could do this by taking the coproduct of the structure with itself $\omega$-many times. Furthermore, I believe that if the category had a monadic free-forgetful adjunction (as [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+category#definitions)), we could just take [term algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_algebra) of the finite model and identify it with the "reduced words" in the term algebra. But we do not always have that- for example, there is no "free field".

So is there any hope to be able to do this uniformly, or does it depend in some complicated way on the theory given/ the category of models of this theory?

EDIT: As pointed out by @EricWofsey, it is not going to be possible in general to hope for the coproduct to be in the same category since the theory may have no infinite models at all, so I would modify the question to asking for existence of a coproduct in some "associated" category.

EDIT2: We should also rule out from consideration theories for which only the empty set is a model.

Comment: This certainly isn't possible in general; your theory might have no infinite models at all.

Comment: Of course! I should refine this somehow to deal with this obvious problem. For example, this is obviously impossible to do for the theory of finite fields, but one could always construct an algebraic closure of a given finite field and there is a clear way in which the original finite field embeds in the closure. So perhaps I do not strictly want the infinite coproduct to be in the same category, but in some maybe "associated" category?

Comment: There is no reason to think such an "associated" category exists.  For instance, what if you just have the theory of empty sets?

Comment: Right, I thought I was excluding this when I said my signature was nonempty, but I suppose we could just have one contradictory sentence. So I should *also* exclude that. Also I do not think an "associated" category should exist in general, but it would be interesting to know what conditions allow for one to exist or not.

Comment: @BigSocks The theory of a contradictory sentence has no models at all. The theory of empty sets referred to by Eric Wofsey has exactly one model, namely $\emptyset$. (This theory is axiomatized by $\forall x \bot$).

Comment: Oh oops, well I learned something today! Thank you